# Can we reset context without removing one of the parameters from the context in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

In Dialogflow I have event context which is carried in all the intents, it has various information like the event id, app id, ip address and location as parameters in it.

When I am trying to reset the context, I want to remove all the parameters except event id. How can I do it?  I have tried doing:

`context_obj = 
{'name': context['name'], 'lifespan': 5,                                  'parameters': {'event_id': context['parameters']['event_id']}}`

But this does not seem to reset the other parameters.

Comment: `'parameters'` are also present as a separate object in the request body. Try updating those values and see.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code about how you're using `context_obj`?